# next nine births at a hospital all being girls determine whether the event is independent or dependent and find the probability

Tags: probability

next nine births at a hospital all being girls

determine whether the event is independent or dependent and find the probability

I found the event as independent and probability being 1/9 is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "independent or dependent" here, exactly?

Comment: if you mean P(nine births all being girls) = .5^9 ... not 1/9

Comment: You may have been supposed to assume the events are independent, but in reality I think they are not. Some percentage of births are identical twins, and identical twins are always either both girls or both boys. Hence knowing the that first child born in a certain hospital on a certain day was a girl raises the chance (slightly) that the second child born was a girl. So the answer to the question depends on how detailed a model of actual births we were supposed to use--for example, to simplify things we might assume no twins and equal chances of a boy or a girl.

Answer (score 1):

Dependent probabilities are ones that are tied together, one measurement can influence the next, think of a bag with 2 red counters and 2 blue counters, what are the odds of your second draw being a red counter? It depends on the first draw because the contents of the bag will change.

Independent probabilities do not get influenced like this, (put the counters back after drawing)

Because of this, yes, the answer you want is "independent".

For the second half of your question, this is the same as figuring the odds of rolling a die multiple times.
You need to multiply for this,  If you want two rolls of 6 in a row then you first need to roll a 6 on the first try (1/6 chance)  You then need to roll a 6 on the second try (1/6) and you just multiply them.
Apply this to your problem and you will find the answer you need.